# How to bind functions to templates in angular-schema-form?

Tags: angular-schema-form

I am using the [angular-schema-form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form) library, and I want to use a custom template and bind a function in my angular service to the element's native `onchange`-attribute.

Here is my code:

```
var myOnChange = function(){
    console.log("test);
}
var form = [{
    "key":"attachment",
    "type":"template",
    "title":"Attachment",
    "template":"<input onchange=\"myOnChange()\" type=\"file\" accept=\"image/*\" >"
}];
var schema={"attachment":{"type":"object"}}
```

With this code, I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: myOnChange is not defined`-error.

**EDIT:**
If i try to just write the following in the template:

`"<input onchange=\"console.log('test')\" type=\"file\" accept=\"image/*\" >"`

I am able to write "test" in the console